# "redirect permanent" doesn't stop

Tags: debian, ssl, redirect, apache2

I configured SSL/TLS for a site, and added a redirect line to the original config.

```
Redirect permanent / https://mypage/
```

And it worked fine. Now i was tasked to make it back. I deleted the SSL-based config file, and removed the redirect line, but it doesn't work. The page keeps redirecting. Tried from entirely different device, different browser, incognito mode, and asked a collegue to try it, and it still redirects for him too.

So how do i stop this redirecting? Is there some sort of cache file on the server to delete, or is there some special command to end permanent redirect, or i must do something extreme?

**EDIT:** i tried deleting the tmp files from the page's folder, and the cache files from the /var/cache/apache2

Comment: is it possible that you have the same redirect configured on another vhost? like the http one?

Comment: I guess it really is permanent then :-) Did you reload the server and check the configuration? Can you find something in the error logs?

Comment: I restart the apache2 service after each modification.

Comment: [mod_info](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_info.html) will show you the configuration, so you can tell if it's what you think it is.

Answer (score 2):

A permanent redirect is a permanent one, as the name implies. The information about the redirect are stored at the browser. Once the browser has visited the page once it will remember this redirect and not even try the original page. To fix this the cache need to be deleted in all browsers which have visited the page and which thus cached the permanent redirect. This can not be triggered from the server side.